Approximate moments of transformed RV using Taylor series
In Casella and Berger pg. 241, they argue that if $T$ is a random variable with mean $\theta$,
$$g(T) - g(\theta) = g'(\theta)(\theta - T) + R(\theta, T),$$
where the remainder $R(\theta, T)/(\theta - T) \to 0$ as $T \to \theta$ by Taylor's theorem,
so we can ignore the remainder and take expectations of both sides and conclude $E[g(T)] \approx g(\theta)$. Why are we allowed to discard the remainder? We are taking expectations of both sides and not sending $T \to \theta$. Isn't it possible that the higher moments are relevant and contribute significantly to the expectation?
